# Typescript cast string to array not working

Tags: typescript

I try to cast a string given in terminal args to an array of custom type but the compiler still thinks it's a string and doesn't allow me to do a for each.
Here is the code

```js
type Delivery = [number, number];

const deliveries: [Delivery] = (argv[2] as unknown) as [Delivery];

function sampleChecks() : Boolean {
    console.log(typeof deliveries); // prints string
    let deliveriesToCheck: number[] = [];
    deliveries.forEach(delivery => {  // doesn't work
        deliveriesToCheck.push(delivery[0], delivery[1]);
    });
```

And I run with ``tsc && node app/deliveryChecker.js "[[1,2],[3,4]]" "[1,2,3,4]"```

Comment: `[Delivery]` is probably not what you want. It is a tuple type with one element, not an array. Array types in TypeScript are written as `Delivery[]`.

Comment: As @Clashsoft suggested. It's not the way you specify an array. Casting to array can be done like const deliveries: Delivery[] = argv[2] as Array<Delivery>;

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't have *casting*, it has *type assertions*. They have no effect at runtime whatsoever. (In constrast, in languages with casting, casting often has both a compile-time type effect and also a runtime value effect [and other times, just a compile-time type effect].) The only purpose of a type assertion is to tell TypeScript what the type of something already is when TypeScript doesn't know it. (For this reason, it's best to avoid them when possible.)

Your code is taking `argv[2]`, which (assuming it's `process.argv[2]`) is `string`¹, and telling TypeScript that it's a `[Delivery]` (where `Delivery` is `[number, number]`). That's incorrect, it's a `string` (or `undefined` if `2` is beyond the end of the array) and asserting something else doesn't help you. Separately, given the value you've provided, it's a `Delivery[]` (array of `[number, number]`), not a `[Delivery]` (a tuple type with exactly one `[number, number]` inside it).

If you need to *convert* `argv[2]` from `string` to `Delivery[]`, given the value `[[1,2],[3,4]]`, you could use `JSON.parse` to do that. The direct, naive way is:

```
const deliveries = JSON.parse(argv[2]) as Delivery[];
```

That does (sadly) need the type assertion on the result of the conversion, since `JSON.parse`'s return type is `any`.

Since it's better to avoid (unchecked) type assertions, we could use a function that checks at runtime that the assertion is correct:

```typescript
function parseDeliveries(deliveries: string): Delivery[] {
    try {
        const result = JSON.parse(deliveries);
        if (!Array.isArray(result)) {
            throw null;
        }
        for (const value of result) {
            if (!Array.isArray(value) ||
                value.length !== 2 ||
                typeof value[0] !== "number" || typeof value[2] !== "number"
               ) {
                throw null;
            }
        }
        return result as Delivery[];
    } catch {
        throw new Error(`expected an array of [number, number], got ${JSON.stringify(deliveries)}`);
    }
}
```

Then:

```typescript
const deliveries = parseDeliveries(argv[2]);
```

---

¹ I would have expected `process.argv[2]` to be `string | undefined` if you don't have a `length` check on it, but I checked it it just came back `string`.